# PlanetScope Image Delivery to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, api, planet

I am trying to order PlanetScope data from Planet Explorer and have it delivered directly as an asset to my image collection in Google Earth Engine, but it is unclear how to do this.  I have read and implemented everything the [documentation](https://developers.planet.com/docs/integrations/gee/quickstart/) and watched the one [youtube video](https://youtu.be/ccuewbvZbRM) on this subject, yet I still cannot figure out how to send the order (of my selected scenes) to my account.  This is my first time working with Planet imagery, so perhaps this task is more straightforward than what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same topic, and the documentation available is not enough. What I can tell is that you should follow this link:

https://samapriyaroy.medium.com/order-up-using-and-building-with-planet-s-new-ordersv2-api-ba2fe14eac8e

You need the windows command line, install python on your computer, then install the planet library, and create an order copying and pasting from the block note.

```
pip install planet
planet init
planet orders create
```

However, I still do not know where the Planet image is downloaded on my computer, or how to specify the GEE asset collection.

In case you made any progress on this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following this [notebook](https://github.com/planetlabs/notebooks/blob/master/jupyter-notebooks/orders/ordering_and_delivery.ipynb) by Planet. Then while ordering, change the request to add the delivery options as also shown [here](https://developers.planet.com/docs/integrations/gee/delivery/#example-gee-delivery-payloads). Note that the ImageCollection that you are trying to deliver imagery to, must already exist in GEE.

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't access the Planet's notebook, this is its new directory: https://github.com/planetlabs/notebooks/blob/665f165e59f2c3584976ad2dde569c649e631c0b/jupyter-notebooks/orders_api_tutorials/ordering_and_delivery.ipynb